(México) Significado de "Hacer la mendiga"
En un podcast mexicano sobre hábitos de "dating" de los de Gen-Z escuché una frase que desconocía:
"Hacer (a alguien) la mendiga"
¿Se interpreta literal o metafóricamente?

Te falta el podcast, crack. Sin la fuente es imposible responder a este tipo de preguntas.

Cual es el podcast, a mi tambien me gustaría escucharlo. He estado buscando algo donde pueda aprender y escuchar más el español cotidiano y coloquial

Por la descripción de la pregunta, es más que probable que se trate de la expresión "mendigar amor". Esto significa entregarse completamente al amor de otra persona, a expensas de la propia personalidad, siendo totalmente dependiente del amor de la otra persona.
